# PHP how to insert array into every array in an array with a loop

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
array(n){
            [0]=>
            array(3){
                ["a"]=>int(1)
                ["b"]=>int(2)
                ["c"]=>int(3)
            }
            ...
        }
```

and this array:

```
array(n){
            [0]=>
            array(m){
                ["1x"]=>string(someText)
                ["2x"]=>string(someText)
                ["3x"]=>string(someText)
                ....
            }
            ...
        }
```

I would like to combine them to:

```
array(n){
            [0]=>
            array(3){
                ["a"]=>int(1)
                ["b"]=>int(2)
                ["c"]=>int(3)
                ["x"]=>array(m){
                    ["1m"]=>string(someText)
                    ["2m"]=>string(someText)
                    ["3m"]=>string(someText)
                    ...
                }
            }
            ...
        }
```

i've tried looking around, but haven't found a solution for that problem i have.

i'd really appreciate ,if someone could point me at solution for this issue i have.

**HUGE THANKS for anyone who might help !**

Comment: post the code you tried

Comment: Where does PDO fit in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have 2 arrays: main array and a secondary array (which you want to embed). 
You want to take the main array, which holds nested arrays in it, and manipulate it by merging each nested array with the secondary array.

Here is a working code:

```
// The main array, which we will append to  
$mainArr = array( 
    array (
            "a" => 1,
            "b" => 2,
            "c" => 3
    ),
    array (
            "d" => 4,
            "e" => 5,
            "f" => 6
    )
);

// The Array we want to embed to each of the nested arrays in $mainArr
$arrayToEmbed =  array( 
    "1x" => "Str1x",
    "2x" => "Str2x",
    "3x" => "Str3x"
);

// The final result array that will contain the changes
$resultArr = $mainArr;

// Loop over each nested array in $mainArr and merge with $arrayToEmbed  
foreach( $mainArr as $key => $nestedArr ){
    $resultArr[$key] = array_merge($nestedArr, $arrayToEmbed);
}

// Print final result
print_r($resultArr);
```

Comment: Thank you @Z-Bone for your answer !!
I added "[ ]" brackets to $resultArr[$key] like that:   `$resultArr[$key][] = $arrayToEmbed;`   it works like i intended.